# YITH Woocommerce compare - как сменить текст в описании товара?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

В плагине YITH Woocommerce compare в поле description выводится короткое описание товара (woocommerce_short_description), а нужно полное (у меня оно в табе выводится #tab-description). Может кто знает где это сменить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image]

Comment: Так вы вроде нашли и показали кусок кода, ГДЕ сменить. В чем проблема?

Comment: проблема в том, что я не знаю как задать туда информацию с #tab-description правильно. Я пытался редактировать тот кусок кода, но ничего не получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрел я код этого плагина.

Попробуйте изменить обведённый вами участок кода следующим образом:

```
case 'description':
    $description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_description', yit_get_prop( $product, 'post_content' ) );
    $product->fields[$field] = apply_filters( 'yith_woocompare_products_description', $description );
    break;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, работает! Но маленький нюанс - я использую плагин qtranslate и у меня в этом поле отображается сразу 2 языка. Не знаете как можно исправить?

Comment: А до предложенного мною изменения - тоже два языка было?

Comment: нет, был один язык

Comment: Это странно. У вас краткое описание имело перевод?

Comment: да, было с переводом

Comment: непонятно, отчего так может быть. Я с QTranslate знаком плохо, задайте другой вопрос. На ваш я ответил - собственно заменил обращение к краткому содержанию на обращение к полному тексту. А там уж как QTranslate это перехватывает, не знаю.

Comment: Ок, спасибо и на том, уже сам дальше поковыряюсь

Comment: Судя по всему, неправильно задан параметр 'woocommerce_description', но пока не нашел как правильно записать

Comment: Это вообще не имеет отношения к теме))) woocommerce_description - этл фильтр, который, скорее всего, и не включен )